# Is there a way to unfocus the SearchBar?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want the SearchBar to be unfocus after the user enters 3 characters, otherwise he has to tap outside the SearchBar to unfocus and then tap on a result. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can focus hidden element to blur the input

Answer (score 0):

You can use refs in react to control focus.
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html